# Is it possible to load some class fields and methods after checking some condition in Java

Tags: java, reflection

If I have a Java class with some fields and methods and if I want to use certain fields and methods if only some condition is true, how can I do it in Java? Is it possible with Java reflexion or statically somehow?
In details I can explain it as follows, suppose I have a Java class

```
public Class Myclass{
    public int Version;
    private long Field01;
    private long Field02;
    private void Method01();
    private void Method02();
    //some other methods ..
}
```

Now I want the field `Field01` and method `Method01()` only be loaded if the filed `Version` is equal int value of 4 (it can be any int number as I wish). Is there any way to do that in Java? May be statically?

Comment: Why? Why would anyone want to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "loaded"?

Comment: What do you mean by "be loaded". Your class looks the way it does, you can't hide stuff. What problem are you trying to solve? Class evolving over time having to keep backward compatibility?

Comment: This sounds like a bad plan that there's almost certainly a better way to approach if you think about the problem completely differently, e.g. if you have a `MyClassVersion4 extends MyClass` with only the special fields necessary for version 4.

Comment: @LouisWasserman than you very much sir, I understand your idea with extended version4 but  suppose,  an instance of this class is created after a button click event and initiate with version =5 and so on. Then I need again another extension class ??

Comment: Well, what fields do you expect to have in that version? Either you know all the fields each version should have in advance, or you don't.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I know which fields and methods I want relates to each version. My approach is using switch case according to version number , use needed fields. But  then I have to declare all the fields in which I'm  not gonna use some  depending on the version number . Hope you understand the point now

Comment: In that case, you might as well leave all the fields in and accept that some of them will be empty.

Comment: @LouisWasserman that's what I did. But I am looking for some elegant way if you know. Because declaring 100 of fields that I am not really using in a certain version is an overhead in writing and that make source cord too long

Comment: If you have 100s of fields that probably means you should be breaking them into smaller classes in the first place.  Having hundreds of fields is a problem *by itself* to solve with better design.

Comment: @LouisWasserman you men another design approach as I understand. Is it hard or impossible to use java reflection for that case? Or is it bad practice to use reflection to load dynamically ? Excuse me, I have not much experiences in reflection framework

Comment: Using reflection probably couldn't solve your problem and is almost certainly a terrible idea anyway.  You need to solve the root issue, which is that if you have a Myclass object there are hundreds of separate fields it could possibly have.  Fix that first.

Comment: @LouisWasserman the root issue is that  depending on the version thous fields shod get filled with  different datas from different data tables

Comment: It sounds like you should have a class corresponding to each data table, and then build more things out of those classes.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes ! exactly it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a more extensible approach...

```
public class MyClass {

    long version;
    long field;
    Runnable methodRunnable;

    public MyClass(long version) {
        this.version = version;

        if (version == 4) {
            field = 10; // Example
            methodRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // ... Implementation here...
                }
            };
        } else {
            field = 5;
            methodRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Implement here...
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public void method() {
        methodRunnable.run();
    }
}
```

Java 8 would make the invocation a little neater for the `methodRunnable = () -> {}`.  And naturally, pulling this out of the constructor would be nice...

Edit:
If you have a significantly more complicated set up like you say, I would go down an interface/implementation/factory approach.

```
interface ThingDoer {
    long getField();
    void method();
}

class ThingDoerImpl1 implements ThingDoer {
    @Override
    public long getField() {
        return 4L;
    }
    @Override
    public void method() {
        // Implement me here...
    }
}

class ThingDoerImpl2 implements ThingDoer {
    @Override
    public long getField() {
        return 25L;
    }
    @Override
    public void method() {
        // Implement me here...
    }
}

class ThingDoerFactory {
    static ThingDoer getFromVersion(long version) {
        if (version == 4L) {
            return new ThingDoer1();
        } else {
            return new ThingDoer2();
        }
    }
}
```

You can make some sort of Map/switch/whatever to handle the `getFromVersion` method, and it keeps the code for each implementation separate so it's easier to see what's doing what.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. It is very nice that you brought thet approach with Runnable. I can improve on that. But the real case is insted of haviing two possible cases for version , what if I have 100 or more possiblities for that value of version? Any idea insted of writting 100 swich cases ??

Comment: @Lakshi see my edit.  If you can't actually generate the methods _from_ the version, I'd have a `Map<Long, Producer<ThingDoer>>` (or just `ThingDoer` if you don't need a new one each time) and call that with `version` as the `key`.

Comment: sorry for the delay . The Edited version helped me a lot. Thank you very much.